# How to use ClassValue as type cache that has put() method?

Tags: java, caching

I would like to use `ClassValue` as a type cache. However, I would like to assign some values to a type. For that, I can not use `computeValue()`, as mapping is defined outside, i.e. is not pre-deterministic.

I see there is a `put` method in `ClassValue` but it is not accessible.

There is also no sense to have a `Map<Class, ?>` in my `ClassValue` implementation.

I wonder if using class names instead of `Class` is a better option?

How to use `ClassValue` as a cache?